# params.id coming to be undefined in getServerSideProps in next.js after first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, dynamic-routing

I have implemented dynamic routing in my Next.js project. I am trying to access the param in the URL it comes as expected in the initial render but then comes undefined. I have implemented it elsewhere in my file but in this one file is it creating the error. I am attaching the code snippet and the screenshots.

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  console.log(params);
  const res = await getEvent(params?.id as string);
  return {
    props: {
      event: res.event,
    },
  };
};
```

This is the console showing it get undefined after first render:

[image]

Here's the whole code for the page:-

```
import { bookEvent, getEvent, razorpay, setStatus } from "@actions/event";
import { NextPageContext } from "next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import { Event, EventStatus } from "@typings/event";
import { format, parse, formatISO } from "date-fns";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { css } from "@emotion/css";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    Razorpay: any;
  }
}
interface Props {
  event: Event;
}

function mergeDateandTime(date: string, time: string) {
  return `${date.split("T")[0]}T${time.split("T")[1]}`;
}
const EventPage = (props: Props) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { data: session } = useSession();
  const user = session?.user;
  const {
    title,
    description,
    date,
    time,
    price,
    poster,
    banner,
    id,
    users,
    owner,
    status,
  } = props.event;
  const [bought, setBought] = useState(false);
  const [isOwner, setIsOwner] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (user && owner === user.email) {
      setIsOwner(true);
    } else if (user && users && users.includes(user.email)) {
      setBought(true);
      setIsOwner(false);
    } else {
      setBought(false);
      setIsOwner(false);
    }
  }, [user]);
  const finalDate = mergeDateandTime(
    formatISO(new Date(date)),
    formatISO(parse(time, "HH:mm", new Date()))
  );
  const showRazorpay = async () => {
    const res = await razorpay(id);
    const options = {
      readonly: {
        email: 1,
      },
      notes: {
        event_id: id,
      },
      key: `${process.env.RZP_KEY}`,
      amount: res.amount,
      currency: "INR",
      name: "Stagio",
      description: `booking for ${title}`,
      image: "https://example.com/your_logo",
      order_id: res.id,
      handler: async function (response: {
        razorpay_payment_id: string;
        razorpay_order_id: string;
        razorpay_signature: string;
      }) {
        alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
        alert(response.razorpay_signature);
      },
      prefill: {
        name: user.username,
        email: user.email,
      },
      theme: {
        color: "#3399cc",
      },
    };
    var rzp1 = new window.Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.on(
      "payment.failed",
      function (response: {
        error: {
          code: any;
          description: any;
          source: any;
          step: any;
          reason: any;
          metadata: { order_id: any; payment_id: any };
        };
      }) {
        alert(response.error.code);
        alert(response.error.description);
        alert(response.error.source);
        alert(response.error.step);
        alert(response.error.reason);
        alert(response.error.metadata.order_id);
        alert(response.error.metadata.payment_id);
      }
    );
    rzp1.open();
  };
  const startEvent = async () => {
    const res = await setStatus(id, EventStatus.Started);
    router.push(`/room/${id}`);
  };
  const endEvent = async () => {
    const res = await setStatus(id, EventStatus.Ended);
  };
  const buyTicket = () => {
    if (!session?.user) {
      toast.dark("Please Login To Buy Ticket");
    } else {
      showRazorpay();
    }
  };
  const cancelBooking = () => {};
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        width: "100%",
        height: "calc(100vh - 60px)",
        backgroundImage: `url(${banner})`,
        backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          width: "100%",
          backgroundColor: "#000000",
          WebkitMaskImage:
            "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 50%, transparent 100%)",
          padding: 100,
        }}
      ></div>
      <div
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          zIndex: 2,
          top: "20vh",
          paddingLeft: 20,
        }}
      >
        {isOwner && (
          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              width: "100%",
              padding: 10,
            }}
          >
            <p
              className={css({
                color: "#ffffff",
                fontSize: 20,
              })}
            >
              Edit Event
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            width: "100%",
            padding: 10,
          }}
        >
          <p style={{ color: "#ffffff", fontSize: 50, fontWeight: 800 }}>
            {title}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            padding: 10,
            color: "#d94b58",
            fontSize: 30,
            fontWeight: 600,
          }}
        >
          <p>
            {format(new Date(date), "dd MMMM yyyy")}{" "}
            <span style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>|</span>{" "}
            {format(parse(time, "HH:mm", new Date()), "hh:mm a")}
          </p>
        </div>
        <div style={{ padding: 10, fontSize: 20 }}>
          <p style={{ color: "#ffffff" }}>{description}</p>
        </div>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: "row",
            padding: 10,
            alignItems: "center",
          }}
        >
          <div style={{ display: "flex", alignItems: "center", fontSize: 20 }}>
            <p style={{ margin: 0, paddingRight: 10, color: "#ffffff" }}>
              &#8377; {price}
            </p>
          </div>
          <Button
            style={{
              border: "none",
              backgroundColor: "#d94b58",
              borderRadius: 20,
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              isOwner || status === EventStatus.Started
                ? startEvent()
                : buyTicket();
            }}
          >
            {status !== EventStatus.Ended
              ? isOwner
                ? "Start Now"
                : bought
                ? status === EventStatus.Started
                  ? "Join Now"
                  : "Already Bought"
                : "Buy Now"
              : "Event Ended"}
          </Button>
          {isOwner && status !== EventStatus.Ended && (
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                endEvent();
              }}
            >
              End Event
            </Button>
          )}
          {bought && status === EventStatus.Idle && (
            <Button
              onClick={() => {
                cancelBooking();
              }}
            >
              Cancel Booking
            </Button>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async ({ params }) => {
  console.log(params);
  const res = await getEvent(params?.id as string);
  return {
    props: {
      event: res.event,
    },
  };
};
export default EventPage;
```

Comment: how are you triggering the second render? GetServerSideProps is called on every request. so do you mean refershing the page?

Comment: @TusharShahi I have no clue how a second render is being generated. Is it due to the useEffect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debugged it myself. I had an undefined image url in backgroundImage so it was causing the page to re render itself I don't know why.